# Chat Sessions/Events (suggestions for date/name/subjects)

Tags: feature-request, chat

I asked in the main chat room our noble moderator [*goldPseudo*](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/22/goldpseudo) about the possibility of starting chat sessions and he replied as follows:

> We can definitely schedule organized chat sessions, it's just a matter of having enough people interested in actually having one (both participating and organizing).
>   you can bring the topic up on meta, and if/when there's enough support around actually holding one and a good idea of when it should be held, just flag a moderator to actually set the schedule.
>   Any moderator can schedule either one-time events or regular recurring events. Just a matter of knowing when and what the event is supposed to be.

So what are your suggestions?

Comment: what are chat sessions about? I don't have much idea.

Comment: @muslim1 Chat sessions are also known as chat events, I think you'll get a much clearer idea by asking about them in [meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chat-event).

Comment: There is already a post for this, see: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/235/chat-events-suggestions

Comment: but I think it is good this is brought up again, +1